# running repository method with query argument reduce

Tags: java, spring, couchbase

I’m trying to add a repository method (find____) on couchbase that will run with Query param which is setted to true (couchbase view has a reduce function) but when running this method i get a conversion exception from spring ("No converter found capable of converting from type java.util.ArrayList to type java.lang.Integer").

I debugged the flow and saw that when method gets invoked by spring data (invocation.proceed()) the argument of "reduce=true" changes to "reduce=false".

Is there another option to get a view from couchbase with reduce?

Thanks!
Yitzchak.